# Redis session appears to reset when (free) Heroku dyno sleeps

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, redis

I'm hosting a Node.js server on the free tier of Heroku (for now), and I'm using Redis to store the user login session (with `connect-redis` in express). The redis database is on the free tier of Redis Cloud (on Redis Labs, so NOT on Heroku).

The issue is each time the Heroku dyno sleeps and wakes up, my users are all logged out, despite the cookie age being months long.

Here is the only place I touch Redis in the code:

```js
/// ... other imports

// Connect to Redis
const redis = require("redis");
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session);

const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
  password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
  legacyMode: true,
});

redisClient.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err);
});

// ...

// Set up session middleware
app.use(
  session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 120, // 120 days
  })
);
```

Is it possible that somewhere when I initialize Redis or `connect-redis` it resets everything? I'm considering switching to JWTs however they aren't a perfect fit for this exact use case. What may be the cause of this issue and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

In Heroku, the free tier of Redis database does not have persistence and will clear itself on shut down / reboots / etcetera.

Quoting from the documentation,

> The hobby tier for Heroku Redis doesn’t persist instance data. If the instance must reboot or a failure occurs, the data on instance is lost.

The solution for this problem is to upgrade your Heroku instance, or if you want to stay at free tier, you may try other services, such as [Redis on Cloud (Redis Labs)](https://app.redislabs.com/#/). It provides a free persistence for 30MB of data in its free tier.

References:

- [Heroku Redis Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis)
- [Heroku Redis Add-On](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Redis Cloud from Redis Labs already. Still, I'm getting this problem.

Comment: redis cloud no more give free persitence for its free tier https://redis.com/redis-enterprise-cloud/pricing/ https://elements.heroku.com/addons/rediscloud#pricing